# sql max date from result set

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to get the max add_dtm for each month,  I have this set.

```
location, read_time,         read_amt, add_dtm
1,        2/7/2013 9:00:00,  5,        2/8/2013 6:00:00
1,        3/20/2013 8:00:00, 5,        3/20/2013 6:30:00
1,        2/20/2013 8:20:00, 5,        2/20/2013 6:35:00
1,        2/7/2013 9:00:00,  5,        2/8/2013 6:00:00
```

so basically i just need the second and third row in my result.

Comment: This is not difficult. [Try something.](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Pick up a book or look at some SQL tutorials.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: Thanks Jack, really helpful.  And it is oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Oracle, you should be able to use windowing functions like `row_number()`:

```
select location, 
  read_time, 
  read_amt,
  add_dtm
from
(
  select location, read_time, read_amt, add_dtm,
    row_number() over(partition by location, to_char(add_dtm, 'MM-YYYY')
                      order by add_dtm desc) rn
  from yourtable
) 
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cc84/5).

Or you can use a subquery that gets the `max(add_dtm)` for each `location` and then join that result back to your table:

```
select t1.location, t1.read_time, 
  t1.read_amt, t1.add_dtm
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select location, max(add_dtm) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by location, to_char(add_dtm, 'MM-YYYY')
) t2
  on t1.location = t2.location
  and t1.add_dtm = t2.maxdate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cc84/7).

The key to both of these queries is that you are grouping the data by month and year to get the max date.

Comment: +1, Congratulations for the legendary badge, you deserve it :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Thanks that was hard to get!